# Reload div and posting data to that same div

Tags: jquery, html

the below code works just fine for me but i ALSO want to reload the `feed_back` DIV every 3 seconds how can i do this please help

**Post.js**

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var msg = $("#msg").val();
    $.post('realtimemsg.php',{ input:msg },function(data){
        $('#feed_back').html(data);

    });
});
```

**Index.php**

```
   <div id="feed_back"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="post.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            setInterval(function () {
                $('#feed_back').load('#feed_back')
        }, 3000);
    });
```

this is what i have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
var _timer = null;
$('#btn').click(function() {
    clearInterval(_timer);        
    _timer = setInterval(function() {
        var msg = $("#msg").val();
        $.post('realtimemsg.php', {
            input: msg
        }, function(data) {
            $('#feed_back').html(data);

        });
    }, 3000);
})
```

And, you dont need this section:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         setInterval(function() {
             $('#feed_back').load('#feed_back')
         }, 3000);
});
```